# Timestamp like Facebook (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick, timestamp

I am trying to figure out how to make a timestamp like Facebook onClick. I want it to show like Just Now, A Minute Ago, An Hour Ago, Yesterday @ 12:34 pm, so forth and so on. I just can't quite figure it out and don't see anything that anyone has asked for android or java coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one it will help you:

```
public class TimeAgo {
    public static final List<Long> times = Arrays.asList(
            TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(365),
            TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30),
            TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1),
            TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1),
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1),
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1) );
    public static final List<String> timesString = Arrays.asList("year","month","day","hour","minute","second");

    public static String toDuration(long duration) {

        StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0;i< Lists.times.size(); i++) {
            Long current = Lists.times.get(i);
            long temp = duration/current;
            if(temp>0) {
                res.append(temp).append(" ").append( Lists.timesString.get(i) ).append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "").append(" ago");
                break;
            }
        }
        if("".equals(res.toString()))
            return "0 second ago";
        else
            return res.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(toDuration(123));
        System.out.println(toDuration(1230));
        System.out.println(toDuration(12300));
        System.out.println(toDuration(123000));
        System.out.println(toDuration(1230000));
        System.out.println(toDuration(12300000));
        System.out.println(toDuration(123000000));
        System.out.println(toDuration(1230000000));
        System.out.println(toDuration(12300000000L));
        System.out.println(toDuration(123000000000L));
    }}
```

//Output like

3 hours ago

1 day ago

14 days ago

4 months ago

3 years ago

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Prettytime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) to do this.
Like this -

```
PrettyTime prettyTime = new PrettyTime(Locale.getDefault());
String ago = prettyTime.format(new Date(time));
```

Comment: This answer seems better! Please add an example of usage.